# Как задать команду элементу combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как задать команду одному из элементов `Combobox?`

```
w = Tk()
combo = Combobox(w,values=['1','2'],state='readonly')
combo.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

**Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при выборе варианта 1 появлялся любой виджет**

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привязываетесь к событию переключения комбобокса, при срабатывании события проверяете, тот ли пункт выбран, который вам нужен:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

w = Tk()
combo = Combobox(w, values=['1','2'], state='readonly')

def on_change_selection(event):
    if combo.get() == '1':
        # Если выбрана 1, то выполнить какое-то действие
        print(1)

combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_change_selection)

combo.pack()
w.mainloop()
```